# where endpoint is specified?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

in my web service project, when I try to run it in eclipse, the browser window shows wrong (non-existing) endpoint. I expect my service be available on
`localhost:8080/<servlet-name>/<url-pattern>` as they are pointed in web.xml but it's not so. 
Where the endpoint parameters come from?

Comment: What URL is it showing instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

check if it available within the WSDL file.. as follows

```
<wsdl:service name="HelloService">
<wsdl:port binding="impl:HelloSoapBinding" name="Hello">
<wsdlsoap:address
location="http://localhost:8180/Hello/services/Hello" />
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: I don't seem to have wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

appears in eclipse, when one configure a server to run the service under development, endpoint of the service is in path argument in
`<server_installation_dir>/<server_name_and_version>-config/server.xml`

```
<Context docBase="ServiceName" path="/HereItIs" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ServiceName"/>
```

another place to look:

```
<ProjectDir>/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```